# Import Salesforce Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am a new Salesforce Marketing Cloud user and trying to explore Salesforce Data extensions.

I have got access to client's Marketing Cloud instance, but for some reason, I am not able to view "Import" option under interactions in Email studio. I have already configured the Marketing Cloud connect in Salesforce and also setup the Salesforce Integration in Marketing Cloud.

Am I missing some configuration in Marketing Cloud?

TIA

Comment: I've seen instances where interactions were not available under the 'Interactions' tab, but could still be accessed within Automation Studio. Can you confirm whether or not you have access to these Activities within Automation Studio? Regardless, I'm not certain whether it's a permission issue that can be resolved on your end, but I had support resolve the issue in short time.

Answer (score 2):

@Salesforcesmarty It sounds like either you do not have permission to create/view Import Activities, are assigned to a role where the permission is denied or the Business Unit you're working in has been denied this permission.

If you can access the "Admin -> My Users" section of Email Studio and then view the roles and permissions assigned to you for the Business Unit concerned, this may help you to resolve the issue:

[image]

For more information on managing users, please see online help here:

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/administration/users/

For more details around permissions and roles within Marketing Cloud, the section of help that'll likely be of interest is here:

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/smc_roles/

Comment: Let me try and see if this works. My user as Administrator role, so I was assuming that he would have all necessary permissions.

Comment: I just had a look and my user has "Allowed" permissions for "Import".

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty Do you happen to know what version of Marketing Cloud you're working with. It's not "Basic Edition", is it? Secondly, when you look at the permissions you have assigned, Does the "Result" column say you're "Allowed" for all the necessary actions?

Comment: I am not sure what version the client is on, but I can access Automation studio, so for sure it's not the basic version. Yeah it says "Allowed" for all columns.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty That's definitely not Basic Edition, then. Pretty strange. I'd raise a support case, maybe. Out of interest, what are you looking to import from CRM? You might want to take a look at Synchronized Data Sources - http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/synchronized_data_sources/

Comment: And a further thing to try while you get an answer on the absence of Imports in Interactions is to see if you can access the newer version of these in "Audience Builder -> Contact Builder -> Imports".

Comment: I just called the Customer support. They have moved the "Import Activities" part (Import, Filter, Query, Extract" to the Automation studio as an Activities Menu. However the newer option is not working well with Salesforce import.

Comment: Aha! This is a new account? It's still there in older accounts. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah it's a new account. Thanks for your assistance Andrew. Appreciate it :)

Comment: No worries. For what it's worth, I think moving this stuff out of Email Studio has long made a lot of sense.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty, has your SFMC login been integrated with your SFMC ORG?  To verify this, check the "Salesforce Status" setting on the user under "Admin -> My Users" .    This is needed in order to import from Salesforce reports under this login.

Comment: Yeah I have previously configured this to my SF username. After a bit of struggle, finally I was able to setup the SF Data extension and imported the records to MC. Thanks for checking back :) In addition, I could use your help at few other things I need to look into. What would be the best way to reach you out?